# What is the difference between char*str={"foo",...} and char str[][5]={"foo",...} array definitions?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, arrayofarrays

**Case 1:** When I write

```
char*str={"what","is","this"};
```

then `str[i]="newstring";` is valid whereas `str[i][j]='j';` is invalid.

**Case 2:** When I write

```
char str[][5]={"what","is","this"};
```

then `str[i]="newstring";` is not valid whereas `str[i][j]='J';` is valid.

Why is it so? I am a beginner who already get very confused after reading the other answers.

Comment: Maybe you mean `char * str[] = {"what", "is", "this"};` for the first one?

Comment: Try `char *str[] = {"what","is","this"}; putchar(str[0][0]);` first and `char *str[] = {"what","is","this"}; str[0][0] = 't';` next. You can learn one more thing. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8795576/initializing-a-char-pointer-in-c-why-considered-dangerous after the experiment.

Comment: @ajay brahmakshatriya yes

Comment: Last edit made the answers on this post wrong. Please do not edit if you do not understand the question.

Comment: @haccks the last edit was by OP himself. I agree it invalidates some answers, but the correct question needs to be addressed.

Comment: @ajay The OP may ask a new question if his edit invalidates answers.

Comment: The original question (with `char *str` instead of `char *str[]`) doesn't even make sense, as the OP says "then `str[i]="newstring";` is valid whereas `str[i][j]='j';` is invalid.", which applied to `char *` would mean assigning a pointer value to a char element in read-only string literal memory is "valid".  The descriptions of what is "valid" and "invalid" fit much more for `char *str[]`, which makes for a much more meaningful question.  This is clearly just a typo, as confirmed by the OP.

Comment: @CandyGumdrop Since till time my answer is highly voted, I addressed that in my answer.

Comment: What a waste of bounty :\

Answer (score 26, accepted):

*First of all*: A suggestion: Please read about **[arrays are not pointers and vice-versa](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/)!!**

That said, to enlighten this particular scenario,

- **In the first case**,

  ```
  char*str={"what","is","this"};
  ```

  does not do what you think it does. It is a constraint violation, requiring a diagnostic from any conforming C implementation, as per chapter§6.7.9/P2:

  > No initializer shall attempt to provide a value for an object not contained within the entity
  >   being initialized.

  If you enable warnings, you'd (*at least*) see

  > warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
  >
  > ```
  >   char*str={"what","is","this"};
  > ```

  However, a(ny) compiler with strict conformance turned on, should refuse to compile the code. In case, the compiler chose to compile and produce a binary anyway, the behavior is not withing the scope of definition of C language, it's up to the compiler implementation (and thus, can vary widely).

  In this case, compiler decided this statement to make functionally only same as `char*str= "what";`

  So, here `str` is a pointer to a `char`, which points to a *string literal*. 
  You can re-assign to the pointer,

  ```
  str="newstring";  //this is valid
  ```

  but, a statement like

  ```
   str[i]="newstring";
  ```

  would be *invalid*, as here, a pointer type is attempted to be converted and stored into a `char` type, where the types are not compatible. The compiler should throw a warning about the invalid conversion in this case.

  Thereafter, a statement like

  ```
  str[i][j]='J'; // compiler error
  ```

  is syntactically invalid, as you're using the Array subscripting `[]` operator on something which is not "pointer to complete object type", like

  ```
  str[i][j] = ...
        ^^^------------------- cannot use this
  ^^^^^^ --------------------- str[i] is of type 'char', 
                               not a pointer to be used as the operand for [] operator.
  ```
- **On the other hand, in second case**,

  `str` is an array of arrays. You can change individual array elements,

  ```
   str[i][j]='J'; // change individual element, good to go.
  ```

  but you cannot assign to an array.

  ```
   str[i]="newstring";  // nopes, array type is not an lvalue!!
  ```

---

- **Finally,** [considering you meant to write (as seen in comments)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48315523/what-is-the-difference-between-charstr-foo-and-char-str5-foo#comment83622540_48315523)

  ```
  char* str[ ] ={"what","is","this"};
  ```

  in your first case, the same logic for arrays hold. This makes `str` an array of pointers. So, the array members, are assignable, so,

  ```
  str[i]="newstring";  // just overwrites the previous pointer
  ```

  is perfectly OK. However, the pointers, which are stored as array members, are pointers to *string literal*, so for the very same reason mentioned above, you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), when you want to modify one of the elements of the memory belonging to the string literal

  ```
   str[i][j]='j';   //still invalid, as above.
  ```

Comment: The first part of your answer is not right. If `str` has type `char *`, then `str[i]` is a `char` lvalue, not a pointer. If you assign a string literal to it you'll get at least a warning on compile time *assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast*. And then a segmentation fault on run time for trying to write to constant memory.

Comment: In fact `char*str={"what","is","this"};` is a constraint violation, requiring a diagnostic from any conforming C implementation. [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.7.9p2: "No initializer shall attempt to provide a value for an object not contained within the entity being initialized." (It is IMHO unfortunate that gcc treats this as a non-fatal warning by default.)

Answer (score 16):

The memory layout is different:

```
char* str[] = {"what", "is", "this"};

    str
+--------+      +-----+
| pointer| ---> |what0|
+--------+      +-----+   +---+
| pointer| -------------> |is0|
+--------+                +---+    +-----+
| pointer| ----------------------> |this0|
+--------+                         +-----+
```

In this memory layout, `str` is an array of pointers to the individual strings. Usually, these individual strings will reside in static storage, and it is an error to try to modify them. In the graphic, I used `0` to denote the terminating null bytes.

```
char str[][5] = {"what", "is", "this"};

  str
+-----+
|what0|
+-----+
|is000|
+-----+
|this0|
+-----+
```

In this case, `str` is a contiguous 2D array of characters located on the stack. The strings are copied into this memory area when the array is initialized, and the individual strings are padded with zero bytes to give the array a regular shape.

These two memory layout are fundamentally incompatible with each other. You cannot pass either to a function that expects a pointer to the other. However, access to the individual strings is compatible. When you write `str[1]`, you get a `char*` to the first character of a memory region containing the bytes `is0`, i.e. a C string.

In the first case, it is clear that this pointer is simply loaded from memory. In the second case, the pointer is created via array-pointer-decay: `str[1]` actually denotes an array of exactly five bytes (`is000`), which immediately decays into a pointer to its first element in almost all contexts. However, I believe that a full explanation of the array-pointer-decay is beyond the scope of this answer. Google array-pointer-decay if you are curious.

Answer (score 3):

With the first you define a variable that is a pointer to a `char`, which is usually used as just a *single string*. It initializes the pointer to point to the string literal `"what"`. The compiler *should* also complain that you have too many initializers in the list.

The second definition makes `str` an array of three arrays of five `char`. That is, it's an array of three five-character strings.

---

A little differently it can be seen something like this:

For the first case:

```
+-----+     +--------+
| str | --> | "what" |
+-----+     +--------+
```

And for the second you have

```
+--------+--------+--------+
| "what" | "is"   | "this" |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

---

Also note that for the first version, with the pointer to a single string, the expression `str[i] = "newstring"` should also lead to warnings, as you try to assign a pointer to the ***single `char` element*** `str[i]`.

That assignment is invalid in the second version as well, but for another reason: `str[i]` is an *array* (of five `char` elements) and you can't assign to an array, only copy to it. So you could *try* doing `strcpy(str[i], "newstring")` and the compiler will not complain. It's *wrong* though, because you try to copy 10 characters (remember the terminator) into an array of 5 characters, and that will write out of bounds leading to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: A pointer to a `char` is not "just a single string". It may be a pointer to a string, but a string is by definition a sequence of characters, not a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

- In the first declaration

  ```
  char *str={"what","is","this"};
  ```

  declares `str` a pointer to a `char` and is a scalar. The standard says that

  6.7.9 Initialization (p11):

  > The initializer for a scalar shall be a **single expression, optionally enclosed in braces**. [...]

  That said a scalar type can have braced enclosed initializer but with a single expression, but in case of

  ```
  char *str = {"what","is","this"}; // three expressions in brace enclosed initializer
  ```

  it is upto compilers that how it is going to handle this. Note that what happen to rest of the initializers is a [bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=684635). A confirming complier should give a diagnostic message.

  ```
  [Warning] excess elements in scalar initializer
  ```

  5.1.1.3 Diagnostics (P1):

  > A conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic message (identified in an implementation-defined manner) if a preprocessing translation unit or translation unit contains a violation of any syntax rule or constraint, even if the behavior is also explicitly specified as undefined or implementation-defined
- You claim "*`str[i]="newstring";` is valid whereas `str[i][j]='j';` is invalid.*"

  `str[i]` is of `char`  type and can hold only a `char` data type. Assigning `"newstring"` (which is of `char *`) is invalid. The statement `str[i][j]='j';` is invalid as subscript operator can only be applied to an array or pointer data type.
- You can make `str[i]="newstring";` working by declaring `str` as an array of `char *`

  ```
  char *str[] = {"what","is","this"};
  ```

  In this case `str[i]` is of `char *` type and a string literal can be assigned to it but modifying the string literal `str[i]` points to will invoke undefined behavior. That said you can't do `str[0][0] = 'W'`.
- The snippet

  ```
  char str[][5]={"what","is","this"};
  ```

  declare `str` as an array of arrays of `char`s. `str[i]` is actually an array and as arrays are non modifiable lvalues so you can't use them as a left operand of assignment operator. This makes `str[i]="newstring";` invalid. While `str[i][j]='J';` works because elements of an array can be modified.

Answer (score 1):

Just because you said other answers are confusing me, lets see what is happening with a simpler example first

```
char *ptr = "somestring";
```

Here `"somestring"` is a *string literal* which is stored in **read only data section** of the memory. `ptr` is a pointer (allocated just like other variables in the same section of code) which is pointing to the first byte of that allocated memory.

Hence cnosider these two statements

```
char *ptr2 = ptr; //statement 1 OK
ptr[1] = 'a';     //statement 2 error
```

Statement 1 is doing a perfectly valid operation (assigning 1 pointer to another), but statement 2 is not a valid operation (trying to write into a read only location).

On the other hand if we write:

```
char ptr[] = "somestring";
```

Here ptr is not actually a pointer, but the name of an array(unlike the pointer it doesn't take extra space in the memory). It allocates the same number of bytes as required by `"somestring"` (not read only) and that's it.

Hence consider the same two statements and one extra statement

```
char *ptr2 = ptr; //statement 1 OK
ptr[1] = 'a';     //statement 2 OK
ptr = "someotherstring" //statement 3 error
```

Statement 1 is doing a perfectly valid operation (assigning array name to a pointer, array name returns the address of the 1st byte), statement 2 is also valid because the memory is not readonly.

Statement 3 is not a valid operation because here ptr is not a pointer, It can not point to some other memory location.

---

Now in this code,

```
char **str={"what","is","this"};
```

`*str` is a pointer (`str[i]` is same as `*(str+i)`)

but in this code

```
char str[][] = {"what", "is", "this"};
```

`str[i]` is not a pointer. It is the name of an array.

The same thing as above follows.

Answer (score 0):

To do away with the confusion, you must have proper understanding of pointers, arrays and initializers.
A common misconception amongst C programming beginners is that an array is equivalent to a pointer.

An array is a collection of items of the same type. consider the following declaration:

```
char arr[10];
```

This array contains 10 elements, each of type `char`.

An initializer list may be used to initialize an array in a convenient manner. The following initializes the array elements with the corresponding values of the initializer list:

```
char array[10] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','\0'};
```

Arrays are not assignable, thus the use of initializer list is valid upon array declaration only.

```
char array[10];
array = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','\0'}; // Invalid...
```

---

```
char array1[10];
char array2[10] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','\0'};
array1 = array2; // Invalid...; You cannot copy array2 to array1 in this manner.
```

After the declaration of an array, assignments to array members must be via the array indexing operator or its equivalent.

```
char array[10];
array[0] = 'a';
array[1] = 'b';
.
.
.
array[9] = 'i';
array[10] = '\0';
```

Loops are a common and convenient way of assigning values to array members:

```
char array[10];
int index = 0;
for(char val = 'a'; val <= 'i'; val++) {
    array[index] = val;
    index++;
}
array[index] = '\0';
```

`char` arrays may be initialized via string literals which are constant null terminated `char` arrays:

```
char array[10] = "abcdefghi";
```

However the following is not valid:

```
char array[10];
array = "abcdefghi"; // As mentioned before, arrays are not assignable
```

Now, let us get to pointers...
Pointers are variables that can store the address of another variable, usually of the same type.

Consider the following declaration:

```
char *ptr;
```

This declares a variable of type `char *`, a `char` pointer. That is, a pointer that may point to a `char` variable.

Unlike arrays, pointers are assignable. Thus the following is valid:

```
char var;
char *ptr;
ptr = &var; // Perfectly Valid...
```

As a pointer is not an array, a pointer may be assigned a single value only.

```
char var;
char *ptr = &var; // The address of the variable `var` is stored as a value of the pointer `ptr`
```

Recall that a pointer must be assigned a single value, thus the following is not valid, as the number of initializers is more than one:

```
char *ptr = {'a','b','c','d','\0'};
```

This is a constraint violation, but your compiler might just assign `'a'` to `ptr` and ignore the rest. But even then, the compiler will warn you because character literals such as `'a'` have `int` type by default, and is incompatible with the type of `ptr` which is `char *`.

If this pointer has been dereferenced at runtime, then it will result in a run-time error for accessing invalid memory, causing the program to crash.

In your example:

```
char *str = {"what", "is", "this"};
```

again, this is a constraint violation, but your compiler may assign the string `what` to `str` and ignore the rest, and simply display a warning:

> `warning: excess elements in scalar initializer`.

Now, here is how we eliminate the confusion regarding pointers and arrays:
In some contexts, an array may decay to a pointer to the first element of the array. Thus the following is valid:

```
char arr[10];
char *ptr = arr;
```

by using the array name `arr` in an assignment expression as an `rvalue`, the array decays to a pointer to it's first element, which makes the previous expression equivalent to:

```
char *ptr = &arr[0];
```

Remember that `arr[0]` is of type `char`, and `&arr[0]` is its address that is of type `char *`, which is compatible with the variable `ptr`.

Recall that string literals are constant null terminated `char` **arrays**, thus the following expression is also valid:

```
char *ptr = "abcdefghi"; // the array "abcdefghi" decays to a pointer to the first element 'a'
```

Now, in your case, `char str[][5] = {"what","is","this"};` is an array of 3 arrays, each contain 5 elements.

Since arrays are not assignable, `str[i] = "newstring";` is not valid as `str[i]` is an array, but `str[i][j] = 'j';` is valid since
`str[i][j]` is an array element that is **NOT** an array by itself, and is assignable.

Comment: The reason why `char *ptr = ` in your example does not compile is because you are using the wrong type. The reason why `char*str={"what","is","this"};` in the question does not compile is because it has the wrong number of initializers. It is completely different code.

Answer (score 0):

- To begin with

  ```
  char*str={"what","is","this"};
  ```

  **is not even valid C code <sup>1)</sup>, so discussing it isn't very meaningful**. For some reason, the gcc compiler lets this code through with only a warning. Do not ignore compiler warnings. When using gcc, make sure to always compile using `-std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra`.
- What gcc seems to do when encountering this non-standard code, is to treat it as if you had written `char*str={"what"};`. Which in turn is the same thing as `char*str="what";`. This is by no means guaranteed by the C language.
- `str[i][j]` tries to indirect a pointer twice, even though it only has one level of indirection, and therefore you get a compiler error. It makes as little sense as typing

  `int array [3] = {1,2,3}; int x = array[0][0];`.
- As for the difference between `char* str = ...` and `char str[] = ...`, see [FAQ: What is the difference between char s[] and char *s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s).
- Regarding the `char str[][5]={"what","is","this"};` case, it creates an array of arrays (2D array). The inner-most dimension is set to 5 and the outer-most dimension is set automatically by the compiler depending on how many initializers the programmer provided. In this case 3, so the code is equivalent to `char[3][5]`.
- `str[i]` gives you array number `i` in the array of arrays. You cannot assign to arrays in C, because that's how the language is designed. Furthermore, it would be incorrect to do so for a string anyway, [FAQ: How to correctly assign a new string value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131319/how-to-correctly-assign-a-new-string-value)

---

<sup>1)</sup> This is a constraint violation of C11 6.7.9/2. Also see 6.7.9/11.

Answer (score 0):

### Case 1:

When I write

```
char*str={"what","is","this"};
```

then `str[i]="newstring";` is valid whereas `str[i][j]='j';` is invalid.

**Part I.I**
**`>> char*str={"what","is","this"};`**

In this statement, `str` is a pointer to `char` type.
When compiling, you must be getting a **warning message** on this statement:

```
warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
        char*str={"what","is","this"};
                         ^
```

Reason for the warning is - You are providing more than one initializer to a scalar.
[*Arithmetic types and pointer types are collectively called scalar types.*]

`str` is a scalar and from [C Standards#6.7.9p11](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p11):

> The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression, optionally enclosed in braces. ..

Furthermore, giving more than one initializer to a scalar is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).
From [C Standards#J.2 Undefined behavior](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2):

> The initializer for a scalar is neither a single expression nor a single expression enclosed in braces

**Since it is undefined behavior as per the standard, there is no point in discussing it further**. Discussing *Part I.II* and *Part I.III* with an assumption - `char *str="somestring"`, just for better understanding of `char *` type.
*Seems that you want to create an array of pointers to string. I have added a brief about the array of pointers to string, below in this post, after talking about both the cases.*

**Part I.II**
**`>> then str[i]="newstring"; is valid`**

**No**, this is **not valid**.
Again, the compiler must be giving a **warning message** on this statement because of incompatible conversion.
Since `str` is a pointer to `char` type. Therefore, `str[i]` is a character at `i` places past the object pointed to by `str` [`str[i] --> *(str + i)`].

`"newstring"` is a string literal and a string literal decays into a pointer, except when used to initialize an array, of type `char *` and here you are trying to assign it to a `char` type. Hence the compiler reporting it as a warning.

**Part I.III**
**`>> whereas str[i][j]='j'; is invalid.`**

Yes, this is invalid.
The `[]` (subscript operator) can be used with array or pointer operands.
`str[i]` is a character and `str[i][j]` means you are using `[]` on `char` operand which is invalid. Hence the compiler reporting it as an error.

### Case 2:

When I write

```
char str[][5]={"what","is","this"};
```

then `str[i]="newstring";` is not valid whereas `str[i][j]='J';` is valid.

**Part II.I**
**`>> char str[][5]={"what","is","this"};`**

This is absolutely correct.
Here, `str` is a 2D-array. Based on the number of initializers, the compiler will automatically set the first dimension.
The in-memory view of `str[][5]`, in this case, would be something like this:

```
         str
         +-+-+-+-+-+
  str[0] |w|h|a|t|0|
         +-+-+-+-+-+
  str[1] |i|s|0|0|0|
         +-+-+-+-+-+
  str[2] |t|h|i|s|0|
         +-+-+-+-+-+
```

Based on initializer list, the respective elements of 2D-array will be initialized and the rest of the elements are set to `0`.

**Part II.II**
**`>> then str[i]="newstring"; is not valid`**

Yes, this is not valid.
`str[i]` is a one-dimensional array.
As per the C Standards, an array is not a modifiable lvalue.
From [C Standards#6.3.2.1p1](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p1):

> An lvalue is an expression (with an object type other than void) that potentially designates an object;64) if an lvalue does not designate an object when it is evaluated, the behavior is undefined. When an object is said to have a particular type, the type is specified by the lvalue used to designate the object. A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that does not have array type, does not have an incomplete type, does not have a const- qualified type, and if it is a structure or union, does not have any member (including, recursively, any member or element of all contained aggregates or unions) with a const- qualified type.

Also, an array name convert to pointer that point to initial element of the array object except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator or the unary & operator.

From [C Standards#6.3.2.1p3](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3):

> Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ''array of type'' is converted to an expression with type ''pointer to type'' that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue.

Since `str` is already initialized and when you assign some other string literal to `i`<sup>th</sup> array of `str`, the string literal convert to a pointer which makes the assignment incompatible because you have lvalue of type `char` array and rvalue of type `char *`. Hence the compiler reporting it as an error.

**Part II.III**
**`>> whereas str[i][j]='J'; is valid.`**

Yes, this is valid as long as the `i` and `j` are valid values for given array `str`.

`str[i][j]` is of type `char`, so you can assign a character to it.
Beware, C does not check array boundaries and accessing an array out of bounds is undefined behavior which includes - it may fortuitously do exactly what the programmer intended or segmentation fault or silently generating incorrect results or anything can happen.

---

Assuming that in the **Case 1**, you want to create an array of pointers to string.
It should be like this:

```
char *str[]={"what","is","this"};
         ^^
```

The in-memory view of `str` will be something like this:

```
      str
        +----+    +-+-+-+-+--+
  str[0]|    |--->|w|h|a|t|\0|
        |    |    +-+-+-+-+--+
        +----+    +-+-+--+
  str[1]|    |--->|i|s|\0|
        |    |    +-+-+--+
        +----+    +-+-+-+-+--+
  str[2]|    |--->|t|h|i|s|\0|
        |    |    +-+-+-+-+--+
        +----+
```

`"what"`, `"is"` and `"this"` are string literals.
`str[0]`, `str[1]` and `str[2]` are pointers to the respective string literal and you can make them point to some other string as well.

So, this is perfectly fine:

```
str[i]="newstring";
```

Assuming `i` is 1, so `str[1]` pointer is now pointing to string literal `"newstring"`:

```
        +----+    +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+--+
  str[1]|    |--->|n|e|w|s|t|r|i|n|g|\0|
        |    |    +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+--+
        +----+
```

But **you should not do this**:

```
str[i][j]='j';
```

*(assuming `i=1` and `j=0`, so `str[i][j]` is first character of second string)*

As per the standard attempting to modify a string literal results in undefined behavior because they may be stored in read-only storage or combined with other string literals.

From [C standard#6.4.5p7](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5p7):

> It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the appropriate values. If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.

---

### Additional:

There is no native string type in C language. In C language, a string is a [null-terminated array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string) of characters. You should know the difference between arrays and pointers.

I would suggest you read following for better understanding about arrays, pointers, array initialization:

1. Array Initialization, check [this](https://www.eskimo.com/%7Escs/cclass/notes/sx4aa.html).
2. Equivalence of pointers and arrays, check [this](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html) and [this](https://www.eskimo.com/%7Escs/cclass/notes/sx10e.html).

Answer (score 0):

**case 1  :**

```
char*str={"what","is","this"};
```

First of all above statement is **not valid**, read the warnings properly. `str` is single pointer, it can points to `single` char array at a time not to `multiple` char array.

**bounty.c:3:2: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]**

`str` is a `char pointer` and it's stored in `section` section of RAM but it's `contents` are stored in `code(Can't modify the content` section of RAM because `str` is initialized with `string(in GCC/linux)`.

as you stated *str[i]="newstring"; is valid whereas str[i][j]='j'; is invalid.*

`str= "new string"` is not causing modifying **code/read-only** section, here you are simply assigning `new address` to `str` that's why it's valid but

`*str='j'` or `str[0][0]='j'` is **not valid** because here you are modifying the **read only section**, trying to change first letter of `str`.

**Case 2 :**

```
char str[][5]={"what","is","this"};
```

here `str` is `2D` array i.e `str` and `str[0],str[1],str[2]` itself are stored in `stack section` of `RAM` that means you can change each `str[i]` contents.

`str[i][j]='w';` it's valid because you are trying to stack section contents which is possible. but

`str[i]= "new string";` it's not possible because `str[0]` itself a array and **array is const pointer(can't change the address)**, you can't assign new address.

Simply in **first case** `str="new string"` is `valid` because `str` is `pointer`, not an `array` and in **second case** `str[0]="new string"` is `not valid` because `str` is `array` not a `pointer`.

I hope it helps.